# Highcharts matching specific series points (yaxis) with xaxis?

Tags: jquery, xml, highcharts

I have an XML which contains "dates" in xaxis and data-points for spline series.
xaxis : Contains last one year date from current date,(only market days) say 250 days a year.
Series : 250 points for each dates

**NEW :** (where i removed all my `<samples>` with 0) 
Now the `dates` and `sample` are uneven in numbers. will i be able to plot for this data?

**My XML :**

       `<categories>
                  <dates>2014-10-10</dates>
                  .........
                  <dates>2015-10-10</dates>
        </categories>
        <series>
                  <name>Apples</name>
                  <data>
                        <sample>67</sample>
                         ....
                  </data>
        </series>
        <series>
                  <name>Mangoes</name>
                  <data>
                         <sample>10</sample>
                         <sample>67</sample>
                         ....
                  </data>
        </series>`

**OLD :**

**My XML :**

       `<categories>
                  <dates>2014-10-10</dates>
                  .........
                  <dates>2015-10-10</dates>
        </categories>
        <series>
                  <name>Apples</name>
                  <data>
                         <sample>0</sample>
                         <sample>0</sample>
                         <sample>67</sample>
                         ....
                  </data>
        </series>
        <series>
                  <name>Mangoes</name>
                  <data>
                         <sample>10</sample>
                         <sample>0</sample >
                         <sample>67</sample>
                         ....
                  </data>
        </series>`

**My JQuery :**

`$xml.find("dates").each (function(i,cat){
         options.xAxis.categories.push($(cat).text());
         });
         $xml.find('series').each (function(i,series){
         var s = {
         name : $ (series).find('name').text(),
         data: []
          }
                  $(series).find('data sample').each (function(i,sample){
                  s.data.push($(sample).text());
                  });
           });
options.series.push(s);`

I separated each sample into separate series, so first sample of each series match to the first

date.
Now I have to collect only the **non-zero values** from the 'sample' for all the series, to plot

against corresponding date.
Is that possible? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or else will i be able to make the series with plot '0' as transparent?

Comment: So you want to hide all points in all series that has value of zero?

Comment: yes, exactly. i dont want the series to connect points with values zero. It is okay if the series are disconnected. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it after setting series (in options object).

At the beginning you should iterate over all categories that you have by i.e $.each() function.

```
$.each(options.xAxis.categories, function(i, cat){}
```

Inside this function make a container for sum of all series data that have an index of actual category index. Then iterate over all series with each() and add every data value that is on your actual index.

```
$.each(options.xAxis.categories, function(i, cat){
        sum=0;
        $.each(options.series, function(j,data){
            sum+=data.data[i];
        });
```

Check if sum is equal to 0. On true remove category on actual index by using splice(index, 1), where index mean index you are starting splicing and 1 means number of spliced cells. Also iterate over all series with each() and remove every data cell that is on your index with splice(index,1).

```
if(x===0){
            options.xAxis.categories.splice(i,1);
            $.each(options.series, function(j,data){
                data.data.splice(i,1);
            });
        }
```

All code looks like below:

```
 var x;
$.each(options.xAxis.categories, function(i, cat){
        x=0;
        $.each(options.series, function(j,data){
            x+=data.data[i];
        });
        if(x===0){
            options.xAxis.categories.splice(i,1);
            $.each(options.series, function(j,data){
                data.data.splice(i,1);
            });
        }
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/x6rmtyhv/

Comment: Can u please guide me with my updated XML. I have removed all my '0' elements from the xml. Now is it possble to plot the `sample` against the `dates`. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Well I developed a simple parser for previous XML, each tiem when you modify XML then you need to verfiy and modify your parser as well.

Comment: Thanks! but the problem still persists. The zero's are still getting plotted.That is why i removed '0's from the xml and tried. but, no luck. Can you please suggest any solution.